# How to update view of ViewPager outside PageAdapter?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to update image outside `pageradapter` class, but its not working. I have made it through other way, but its not efficient to do it.

```
int pos = mPager.getCurrentItem();
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mPager.setCurrentItem(pos);
```

It takes a lot of time to show its effect, any other way would be highly appreciated. I have almost more than 20 images, so I can't remove and reinstatiate the view. I am trying to update the image from `options menu`. Looking forward for answers or suggestions. Thanks!

Here is my code

```
public class pageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return Global.imageList.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return view.equals(object);
}
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View container, final int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item, null);
    ImageView ivBackground = (ImageView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.pager_image);

    final ImageView ivFavorite = (ImageView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.fav_image);


    ivFavorite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (!helper.isExist(Global.imageList[position])) {

    int i = helper.insertFavourites(Global.imageList[position]);

                if (i != -1) {

            ivFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_selected);
                }
            } else {

                if (helper.removeFavorite(Global.imageList[position])) {

ivFavorite  .setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_unselected);

                }
            }

        }
    });
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    Global.imageList[position]);

    ivBackground.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    ((ViewPager) container).addView(v, 0);
    return v;

}

@Override
public void destroyItem(View container, int position, Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
}

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use 'setTag'(Object tag) method when you init view - 'instantiateItem()' in your 'PageAdapter', then get that view by 'findViewWithTag(Object tag)'

Comment: on image view I need to settag??

Comment: setTag to your View v
`@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View container, final int position) {
     View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item, null);
    v.setTag("pos" + position);
...
}`
And get view by
`View v = mAdapter.findViewWithTag("pos"+index);`
and update anything you want in v:
`ImageView ivBackground = (ImageView) v
            .findViewById(R.id.pager_image);`
Recommend you use Fragment with FragmentStatePagerAdapter/FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: how to get mAdapter in instantiateItem?

Comment: it should be viewPager.findViewWithTag("pos"+index); instead of mAdapter.findViewWithTag("pos"+index);